# Spurious ld error on macOS (M1 processor)

Tags: macos, clang, ld, cairo, apple-m1

I have a C project which uses `libcairo`. On my intel Mac, compiling Cairo with the attached script produces a `x86_64` static library, which can be used without issue.

On a M1 Mac (Mac mini, though I doubt that's a factor), I've made sure to set `-arch x86_64` everywhere (the output binary is used on Intel). Cairo builds successfully and produces a static library. When building a program that relies on it however, I get the following error message at link stage:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file (...)/lib/libcairo.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cairo_create", referenced from:
      _av_display_new in libavionics.a(display.c.o)
  (...)
```

I've made sure to set the `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` flag to `x86_64` in CMake. I can replicate the problem by creating a dummy project in Xcode and building for x86_64. A dummy project using freetype2 (built using the same method), builds & run without errors. I'm at a bit of a loss here, given that the error message says that the architectures don't match (and yet are both `macOS-x86_64`.

`lipo -info libcairo.a` returns `Non-fat file: libcairo.a is architecture: x86_64`.

My Cairo build script is the following:

```
CAIRO_CONFOPTS_COMMON="--enable-static --disable-egl --disable-glesv2 \
    --disable-glesv3 --disable-glx --disable-gl --disable-valgrind \
    --disable-xlib --enable-ft --disable-shared --disable-xlib-xrender \
    --disable-xcb --disable-svg --disable-full-testing --disable-interpreter \
    --disable-gallium --disable-beos --disable-cogl --disable-directfb \
    --disable-fc --disable-ps --disable-glesv2 --disable-win32 \
    --disable-win32-font --disable-drm --disable-png --disable-script --disable-quartz \
    --disable-wgl --disable-gobject --disable-trace --disable-symbol-lookup --disable-zlib"


ARCH_FLAGS="-arch\\ x86_64\\ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9"

export GNUMAKEFLAGS=--no-print-directory
cd cairo
# Make sure we use the libraries we built, and not the system ones
export pixman_CFLAGS="-I$OUTDIR/include/pixman-1"
export pixman_LIBS="$OUTDIR/lib/libpixman-1.a"
export FREETYPE_CFLAGS="-I$OUTDIR/include/freetype2"
export FREETYPE_LIBS="$OUTDIR/lib/libfreetype.a"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$OUTDIR/lib/pkgconfig"

eval LDFAGS="-fvisibility=hidden\\ $ARCH_FLAGS" \
    CFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden\\ $ARCH_FLAGS" \
    CXXFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden\\ $ARCH_FLAGS" \
    ./configure --prefix=$OUTDIR $CAIRO_CONFOPTS_COMMON $ADDCONF || exit 1
make -j9 || exit 1
make install || exit 1
```

Comment: Does the library link correctly with the traditional flags, `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-flat_namespace"` ?

Comment: Doing that allows it to pass the linking step, but libcairo.a is a static library. When running the executable, it fails on launch with a dyld error saying it cannot locate `_cairo_...` symbols, which makes sense since it isn't a shared library

Comment: I see.  Does the alternative LDFLAGS="`-Xlinker -U -Xlinker _cairo_create"` work for the static lib?